# Xlink: image disappears when href added for hyperlink

Tags: javascript, href, xlink

I am very new to javascript so please bear with me.  I have a simple .jst file for an icon I display.  It works fine if I put just show text about the icon, however, if I try to make the text that is showing a hyperlink, my graphic doesn't display anymore. Can anyone provide an explanation as to why this happens?

Here is the code that shows the icon:

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<image width="21" height="15" x="-7" y="-7" xlink:href="images/folder.png" />

<text style="text-decoration: underline; font-style: italic; fill: rgb(0,0,255);" y="-8" x="2">    
<%=  data.CASE_ID %></text>
</g>
```

And as soon as I try to put in the external link information, everything disappears:

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<image width="21" height="15" x="-7" y="-7" xlink:href="images/folder.png" />

<a xlink:href="<MYURL>"><text style="text-decoration: underline; font-style: italic; fill: rgb(0,0,255);" y="-8" x="2"><%=  data.CASE_ID %></text>
</a>
</g>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the above code is correct.  It was my url that was not working!